# TradingView widget in R-Shiny is not displayed in the dashboard but can be seen in the browser

Tags: html, r, shiny, widget

I'm trying to include a TradingView widget in Shiny, but all I see is a small blank window (of the correct size for the widget) followed by a "EURUSD Rates by TradingView" message. However, when I click on "Open in Browser," the correct information is displayed in the window that was blank in Shiny.

The same happens with other widgets from TradingView and other sites.

If I inspect the element in the Shiny UI I can see the following ...

```
<iframe ...>
 #document
  <html>
   <head></head>
   <body></body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

... which shows that the head and body are empty. However, the Console shows no errors. But if I inspect the same window of the browser, the correct information (that generated the widget) is displayed.

How to make the code below work and display the widget in the Shiny window? Also, how to make it display at a specific location on the screen (instead of the top left corner)?

Thanks

```
# From https://www.tradingview.com/widget/single-ticker/
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$div(
    HTML('
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
    <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
    <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/EURUSD/?exchange=FX" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">EURUSD Rates</span></a> by TradingView</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-single-quote.js" async>
    {
     "symbol": "FX:EURUSD",
     "width": 350,
     "colorTheme": "dark",
     "isTransparent": false,
     "locale": "en"
    }
    </script>
  </div>')))
         

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Are you using Rstudio's viewer to see the shiny app? Don't do that, always run it in your browser to develop Shiny apps. The built-in browser in Rstudio is crappy and has an old chromium version.

Comment: I don't use the Viewer. I use the normal dashboard (the dropdown selection that says, "Run in Window" in the 'Run the Shiny application' selector, hovering at the top of the window). The browser I was referring to appears after clicking in "Open in Browser", once the dashboard opens, and the widget works well there. The widget doesn't work in the dashboard.

Comment: Both viewer and window use Rstudio's built-in browser engine. Do NOT use it.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the recommendation. I added the comment that it works in the browser not because I want to use the browser, but because it may give to somebody a hint of why it works in one environment (the browser) and not in the other (the dashboard). My only interest is to make the code run in the dashboard. Thanks.